# How to use recursion in python to gather a nested list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, recursion

Here is the code

```
def list_all(obj):
    """
    Return a list of all non-list elements in obj or obj's sublists, if obj is a list. Otherwise, return a list containing obj.

    @param list|object obj: object to list
    @rtype: list

    >>> obj = 17
    >>> list_all(obj)
    [17]
    >>> obj = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>> list_all(obj)
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>> obj = [[1, 2, [3, 4], 5], 6]
    >>> all([x in list_all(obj) for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
    True
    >>> all ([x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] for x in list_all(obj)])
    True
    """
    if not isinstance(obj, list):
        return obj
    else:
        return [list_all(x) for x in obj]
```

When I tried `print(list_all([[2,3],[4,5]]))`, it prints out the exactly same input, meaning the code does nothing at all. I think the problem is the `[]` bracket but I can't think of a way to eliminate. Could someone help?

Comment: I can't see your code doesn't work , Please be more specific!

Comment: Just edited, sorry about the confusion

Comment: What are you trying to do? To flatten the list of lists?

Comment: Make a nested list into a single list. i.e. [[1, 2, [3, 4], 5], 6] -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: @DavidZemens That only works for a single level, the OP needs a recursive solution

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
def list_all(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, list):
        return [obj]
    else:
        return [item for sublist in obj for item in list_all(sublist)]        

print(list_all(1))                   # Scalar
print(list_all([[2,3],[4,5]]))       # One level
print(list_all([[2,[3,2]],[4,5]]))   # Two levels
```

Output:

```
 [1]
 [2, 3, 4, 5]
 [2, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: That flattens one layer of nesting, and doesn't handle the case where the top level list has some scalar values and some sub-lists. It's not a meaningful improvement on the [`flatten` recipe from the `itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes); the only difference is that it returns scalars unmodified.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I disagree. The example already shows two levels of nesting.

Comment: mtk99, I don't understand about the downvote. Looks fine for me, I going to vote up your solution. If it is wrong, people should explaing here.

Comment: @mtk99: Your original post (not shown in edit history because no votes or comments had been made, but still cached in my browser on another tab) had the comprehension as `return [item for sublist in obj for item in sublist]`, with no recursive `list_all` call, and the only example was running on `[[2,3],[4,5]]` which didn't display non-uniform nesting. That's what I was objecting to; you changed it, so it now works, but you know as well as I do what I was commenting on.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Your comment came several minutes after my final change. No worries this is not a competition

Comment: @mtk99: Yar (though I couldn't have commented more than a minute or so after the change that added recursion). I don't think the answer as written now is bad ([though `itertools.chain.from_iterable` could speed it up mildly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/364696)), and I'm removing the down-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than constructing a bunch of intermediate `list`s, consider using a generator function. Particularly in Python 3.3+, the code is very simple:

```
def flatten_lists(items):
    if isinstance(items, list):
        for x in items:
            yield from flatten_lists(x)
    else:
        yield items
```

If you need the ultimate result to be a `list`, either you let callers wrap in `list()` themselves, or you define a wrapper to call the generator and convert it to a `list` for them:

```
def list_all(items):
    return list(flatten_lists(items))
```

It dramatically reduces the allocator churn involved in creating and disposing of all the intermediate `list`s compared to non-generator based solutions.

Example:

```
>>> list_all([1, [2, [3, [4, 5], 6]]])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, sorry not tested but is trivial ....

```
def list_all(obj):

    result= []
    if not isinstance(obj, list):
        result.append(obj)
    else:
        for x in obj:
            result += list_all( x )
    return result
```